# Set SSRS Report Privs via Web Service API

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

I'm tasked with creating a utility that takes SSRS reports from a staging location and deploys them to our beta and production environments.  I'm using the ReportingService2005 api.

Copying the reports from server to server is working quite well.  My hang up comes to cloning the security on our SSRS folder structure.  I'd like the security to be setup on staging and copy that setup to beta and then to production.  This does not seem possible with the API.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can mirror folder privs across servers?  I'm so close since the structure copying is working correctly; just need this last piece.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to chalk this up to an ID 10 T error.

```
bool inherit;

// get policies from source and apply to target.
Policy[] policies = _source.GetPolicies(source, out inherit);
_target.SetPolicies(target, policies);
```